# Do not have a usr/share/eclipse/plugins folder for installing a new plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, gnome-terminal, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I need to install a new plugin for my eclipse and when I went through Internet many sources suggested to paste the downloaded jar file in to usr/share/eclipse/plugins which I cannot find in my system. And I'm using *Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS* version of Ubuntu.

Comment: What happens if you just make that dir and put the jar file in it?

Comment: but the eclipse should point to the directory to use it right.

Comment: How and where did you install Eclipse? In that location you will find the /plugins subfolder.

Comment: @Sebastian, Thank you. It does.